# Is there any presence of Virtual Reality in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

Is there any presence of Virtual Reality in Star Wars? Perhaps when the search for the planet lost they used some kind of Virtual Reality, but I'm not sure if that is VR, or just an Holograph.

Comment: Legends or current Canon? Also - as you said re: holograms, perhaps define more clearly what you mean by VR

Comment: Rey uses a flight simulator. Does that count?

Comment: Itchy watches Wookiee porn via some kind of VR setup in "The Star Wars Holiday Special".

Comment: @JohnSensebe yeah, https://youtu.be/S3a5j8PgQxg?t=29m36s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Journey to the Force Awakens - Before the Awakening** (new canon)

FN-2187 (Finn) is in StormTrooper training that takes place in, essentially, a Star Trek-style holodeck.

> The world flickered, froze, and then winked out of existence. Where
>   there had been an unnanmed Republic outpost...there were only four
>   walls and a perfectly flat metal floor. Where there had been a
>   battlefield, there was only the simulation room, vast and empty and
>   cold and sterile.

pg 12

Comment: @Valorum : One could have written "A quote would make the answer even better".

Comment: @Praxis - Yes, that too.

Answer (score 5):

### Disney Canon

In [The Force Awakens: Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey%27s_Story), we learn that Rey's piloting experience is largely as a result of her spending time using a (helmeted) VR simulation of an A-Wing fighter

> The second she saw the TIE zoom out behind her, Rey slammed on her
> reverse thrusters. The TIE fired its blasters, but its targeting was
> completely off. The enemy ship clipped the top of her cockpit and blew
> past her. There was no way the TIE could slow down now. It sped out of
> control, deeper into the narrowing cave. A few seconds later, Rey saw
> the glow of an explosion as the TIE ran into the cave wall.
>
> “YES!” Rey whipped off her helmet and punched the air….   But her
> excitement faded as soon as she looked around her. **It had just been a
> flight simulator, after all, but every time she took off the helmet, a
> part of her hoped she would have miraculously teleported to where she
> really belonged, back with her family—wherever that may be.** She was
> still sitting inside the Imperial walker shell she called home. The
> sun still loomed large as it sank beneath the horizon. The blistering
> desert wind still scratched at her door.

### Extended Universe

In the [Star Wars: Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels), we learn that the Coral Vanda Casino Ship has "adventure rooms" that are essentially indistinguishable from Star Trek style holodecks.

> The Coral Vanda has sixteen luxury suites on the main concourse, and
> also offers four "adventure rooms' which re-create exotic galactic
> locations and are among the most sophisticated amusement facilities to
> be found anywhere. Each adventure room uses a combination of
> holographic generators, tactile arrays, and olfactory emitters to
> create a stunningly realistic simulation. Current offerings include
> Coruscant's Imperial Plaza, the sky cities of Tranthellix, an Ithorian
> herd ship bazaar, and the crystal caverns of Berchest.

There are also "*virtual reality simulators*" mentioned in several novels.

> Colonel Veers’s voice continued. **“You will undergo six weeks of
> intensive training in the virtual reality simulators before being
> allowed in the AT-AT even as an observer.** If you pass the qualifying
> phase of the test, you will be allowed to accompany the AT-AT in one
> of my’combat battalions. Good luck to you all, but take a good look
> around you-fewer than one person in ten will successfully complete
> this arduous training.” He scanned the room as though he could look
> into each recruit’s face. **Davin sat rigid in his seat and tried to
> meet the holo’s eye, but the image dissolved from view.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Tales from the Mos Eisley Cantina](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_from_the_Mos_Eisley_Cantina)</sup></sub>

You may want to note that the image quality is sufficient to trick a cadet into thinking that he's in a *real* attack.